# App crashes when trying to read text file from server Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, crash

Earlier on, when I was developing my app, reading a text file from a server caused no problems. Now, whenever I do so, the app crashes and it says 'Unexpected Error occurred.' I am using the 4.1.2 version API.

Here is code for my main activity:

```
package awsomisoft.yemeb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread() {
        TextView urlTextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.URLtextView);
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try

            {
                String str = "";
                URL url = new URL("myurlhere");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(str);
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1)

            {
            } catch (IOException e)

            {
            }

            urlTextOut.setText(text);
        }
    }.start();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I have looked online and a majority of the solutions involve putting the reading code in a new thread because of the NetworkOnMainThreadException. Is there something wrong with the code that would cause it to crash? I also did add the permissions to the manifest file(the AndroidManifest.xml).

Is there a way to fix this problem? If there is more information needed, just ask and I can provide.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Android Studio, is there an output of logcat anywhere to see the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: To be honest, I am fairly new to it as well. Also, what way would there be to view the error logs on the Nexus?

Comment: Android Studio should pop-up a logcat window automatically when you run the app from the IDE. Like this: http://puu.sh/amdnE/ed2b8e9909.png

Comment: I'm running the app on my tablet.

Comment: Yeah, but are you launching it from Android Studio (using the Run menu) or are you manually transferring the APK to the device and installing it?

Comment: I am manually transferring because of issues I have been running into with the other way of doing it.

Comment: Ah, okay, that would be why you can't see any logs. ADB is used for both installing the app and reading the logcat output from the device. You'll need to get it working somehow if you want to see logs in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you change your TextView not in UI thread. Please find your view in onCreate()

```
TextView urlTextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.URLtextView);
```

and when you change your text:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                urlTextOut.setText(text);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Would I put the runOnUiThread within the Thread or outside of it?

Comment: inside instead of urlTextOut.setText(text);

Comment: I did that and it resulted in an error "Variable 'urlTextOut' is accessed within inner class, needs to be declared final." How would I solve this?

Comment: just make this variable as final.

Comment: if you put this line : urlTextOut.setText(text); in try\catch block then Exception like CalledFromWrongThreadException should be thrown.

Comment: It finally works after me trying to fix it for 12 hours. Thank you a bunch(and to the other people as well). :)

Comment: Just remember that you should work with UI toolkit( like TextViews, EditText and others) from UI thread.

Comment: I can't due to reputation. I would like to, though.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the future, you should be able to view logs, exception stacktraces etc. in your IDE's logcat window. You are launching the app from the IDE, right?
2. I believe your specific issue is caused by the fact that you're trying to access UI elements from a thread other than the UI thread, which isn't possible. You'll need to put your code inside a runOnUiThread() call for this to work.

Comment: Thank you, another user suggested the same solution and it worked.

Comment: Glad it worked. :) Just make sure to mark one of the answers as accepted so people can see your issue was resolved.